# How to show that $\inf A=1$, when $A=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}: 1<x \leq 6 \}$?

Tags: calculus

How to show that $\inf A=1$, when $A=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}: 1<x  \leq 6 \}$?

my own solution: 
(1) true, because $1<x$, $\forall x \in A$

(2) assume $ \exists c \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $c \leq x$, $\forall x \in A$, then 
$c \leq 1$.

Comment: You should argue WHY $c\leq 1$.

Comment: @Clayton: Can you give me some hint how to do that:

Comment: If $c>1$, then $1<(c+1)/2<c$, hence it isn't a lower bound. This means $c\leq 1$ and we're done.

Comment: Clayton: was your proof proof by contrapositive( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive) or Proof by contradiction(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) or was it proof by counterexample?

Comment: Proof by contadiction. Suppose $c>1$, then we find an element less than $c$, which is a contradiction to $c$ being a lower bound. Thus $c\leq1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (1) shows that $1$ is a lower bound for $A$. To see that it's the greatest lower bound, if $c > 1$, then there is an $x \in A$ such that $x < c$ (for example $x = (1+c)/2$).

Comment: mrf: How does this( "to see... ") relates to condition (2)? I mean is this some counterexample to show that (2) holds?

Comment: @alvoutila The argument shows that no number greater than $1$ is a lower bound for $A$. Hence $\inf A = 1$.

Comment: all: By the way, would you define $imf A$ the same way as I did? If not how would you define $imf A$?

Comment: mrf: but I guess that your argument is counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

How about try using the definition of the lower bound? Also, if no element greater than 1 is the lower bound, then you can conclude that infimum is 1.

Comment: user...: what is definition of lower bound? So one should show that c>1 => c is lower bound? but which condition ((1) or (2)) does this mean?